# windows store app 8.1 file system access

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Can windows store apps only access "library" files and not other locations on the hard drives of PCs? Like if I had a D drive that was full of video media that I wanted the app to have access to, is there no way to get to that? I've been searching for a while now and can't find anything but "knownfolder" examples and documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access files outside of the libraries and other specific locations, you'd need to use the FileOpenPicker or FolderPicker. You can find more information on File Access and Permissions for Windows Store apps at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh967755.aspx.

Comment: Thanks. I've see that and on that page it says, "However, you can gain access to files and folders in the user's Downloads folder by calling a file picker (FileOpenPicker or FolderPicker) so that users can navigate and pick files or folders for your app to access." So that says to me it can only pick and access files/folders within the user's Downloads folder. That kind of cripples app development for anything that involves external files. I guess I am surprised it would be limited like that.

Comment: I might have found more info digging into the FolderPicker a little deeper. I'll have to go do a little experimenting and see if it does what I am looking for but you put me on to a possible idea. Thanks.

Comment: I believe StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList is what I was looking for. Stores folders (and files) for future use in the app.