# How to display an image from a network folder or local drive in a Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm having trouble displaying an jpg in an Image control in a Windows Universal App. (I had the same problem trying to create a Windows 8 Store app as well)

I have a simple form with an Image control on it. All I want to do is be able to open images in a folder on my local drive or a network drive on my local network and display them. But I am not having any luck. The only thing I get is E_NETWORK_ERROR, with no additional information.

I assume it probably has something to do with security, but surely there must be a setting or permission to allow me to do it. I tried enabling Private Networks in the Capabilities tab of the manifest, but that didn't help. I don't see anything in Declarations that sounds like what I need.

I know UWP apps are somewhat sandboxed, but if you can't even access local files, what good are they?

Here is a sample of code I have tried. I've done other iterations as well, but they all have the same end result.

Xaml:

```
<Image Name="Image1"/>
```

Code behind:

```
    public LoadImage()
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.ImageFailed += Bitmap_ImageFailed;
        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"D:\Users\Steve\Documents\SomeImage.JPG", UriKind.Absolute);
        Image1.Source = bitmap;
    }

    private void Bitmap_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Write(e.ErrorMessage);
    }
```

When I run it, I end up in the Bitmap_ImageFailed event and the ErrorMessage property is simply "E_NETWORK_ERROR", and nothing is displayed in the Image. Not very helpful.

What am I missing? It has to be something simple and obvious that I am overlooking.

Update:

Thanks to all the suggestions here I was able to get it going. The part I was failing to get through my skull was that you can't just give it a folder and expect it to read a file, even as a "quick & dirty test". You have to go through "proper channels" to get there. I pieced it all together and came up with this example which displays the first image in the selected folder:

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".tif");
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        if (folder != null)
        {
            StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
            var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();

            var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.ImageFailed += Bitmap_ImageFailed;
            var stream = await files.First().OpenReadAsync();
            await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            Image1.Source = bitmap;
        }
    }
```

In addition, I had to add the file types for .jpg, .tif and .png as well as File Open Picker to the Declarations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows store app 8.1 file system access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586675/windows-store-app-8-1-file-system-access)

Comment: Pretty sure you'll have to use a file picker.

Comment: take a look here for documentation as well as C# Example 
[C# Image.Source property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx)

Comment: File picker isn't an option since the ultimate goal is to do batch processing on a folder full of images, and having to select each one individually would defeat the purpose. A folder picker might work if I can open a folder and gain access to all the images within it. Peter's suggested duplicate has something in there about StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList, which sounds interesting since I would also need to be able to gain access to the files in the future without requiring the user to re-choose the folder each time. It's a direction to explore at least. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can figure out all necessary information in MSDN article [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188700.aspx)

In addition to the default locations, an app can access additional files and folders by declaring capabilities in the app manifest (see [App capability declarations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt270968.aspx)), or by calling a file picker to let the user pick files and folders for the app to access (see [Open files and folders with a picker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186456.aspx)).

So if you want to read a file from users document folder you need to update your applications AppXManifest to request the [Document Library Access capability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt270968.aspx).

You also need to update your AppXManifest by declaring what file type(s) you want to access. Then, even with access to the folders, you only have access to a limited set of file types. You have to specify supported files types on Declarations tab

[image]

I set a new file type (.txt) and let it role from there. And code example

```
async void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _Name = "HelloWorld.txt";
    var _Folder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
    var _Option = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting;

    // create file 
    var _File = await _Folder.CreateFileAsync(_Name, _Option);

    // write content
    var _WriteThis = "Hello world!";
    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(_File, _WriteThis);

    // acquire file
    try { _File = await _Folder.GetFileAsync(_Name); }
    catch (FileNotFoundException) { /* TODO */ }

    // read content
    var _Content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(_File);
    await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(_Content).ShowAsync();
}
```