# Image source from disk Xamarin Forms

Tags: image, file, xamarin, uwp

I have a Xamarin Forms app and what I want to do is to set the source of an Image View to a specific Image in my disk in UWP. 
That is to say, I have the absolute path of my image which is in my disk, and I want to set the source of an Image View programmatically.
I have tried using

```
image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(filePath);
```

But it didn't work in UWP, although it does work in Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display an image from a network folder or local drive in a Windows Universal App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071024/how-to-display-an-image-from-a-network-folder-or-local-drive-in-a-windows-univer)

Comment: it's not a duplicate of that question

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do what you want is in your `ViewModel` to use a method where you put the path based on the OS

**View**

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
```

**ViewModel example**

```
public string ImagePath
{
    get
    {
        return _path;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_path != value)
        {
            _path = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImagePath");
        }
    }
}    
private string _path;
```

When you set a path for an image you can use a function like that:

```
public static class OSHelpers {
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the os image path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ImageName">Name of the image.</param>
    /// <returns>System.String.</returns>
    public static string SetOSImagePath(string ImageName) {
        string rtn = ImageName;

        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows || Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone) {
            rtn = "Images/" + ImageName;
        }

        return rtn;
    }
}
```